# how to set value of hidden element in selenium with python?

Tags: python, forms, selenium, post, submit

I am using selenium to perform click a link:

```
<form method="post" action="example.com" id="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />

    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;gvOnLineUser&#39;,&#39;KickOut$0&#39;)">click Me</a>
</form>
```

so as you see when I click the link, it execute a `javascript snippet`:

```
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];

    if (!theForm) {

        theForm = document.form1;

    }

    function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {

        if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {

            theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;

            theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;

            theForm.submit();

        }

    }
```

First, I tried to submit it with click:

```
el = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='form1']/a").click()
```

but this does not execute as I expect, this means it doesn't submit the form.

Then I tried to simulate a post request, but it seems that `selenium` doesn't supply a `post` method.

At last I tried to use `submit()` method, but how can I change the value of these two hidden element value?

Comment: What is happening in the browser when you click the link? Are you sure there are no other forms with the same `id`? Any iframe elements on the page? Any errors? Can you share a link to the website? Thanks!

Comment: @alecxe I have the same case. Can you help me.